# How to improve performance when joining List and Linq object

Tags: c#, performance, linq, indexing

I have one list, read from file:

```cs
var lsData = ReadExcelFile<CustomerEntity>(path);
```

And one Object (loaded into memory):

```cs
lsCustomer = await CustomerService.GetAll()
    .Where(c => c.isDeleted == null || !c.isDeleted.Value)
    .OrderBy(c=> c.Code)
    .ToListAsync();
```

And the join command:

```cs
var lsDuplicateEmail = 
    (from imp in lsData
    join cust in lsCustomer
    on ImportHelpers.GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace(imp.Email) equals ImportHelpers.GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace(cust.Email)
    into gjoin
    from g in gjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
        {
            ImportItem = imp,
            CustomerItem = g,
        }
    into result
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ImportItem.Email) && result.CustomerItem != null 
        && !ImportHelpers.CompareString(result.ImportItem.Code, result.CustomerItem.Code)
    select result);

var lsDuplicateEmailInSystem = lsDuplicateEmail.Select(c => c.ImportItem.Code).Distinct().ToList();
```

I perform test with lsData list about 2000 records, lsCustomer about 200k records.

The Customer Email field is not indexed in the DB.

The join command executes with about 10s (even though the result is 0 records), too slow.

I've looked around and can't seem to index the email field in lsCustomer. I know the reason for the slowness is because the complexity is O(n*m).

Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: The method calls within the query are going to cause performance hit. So pre-process your results, e.g., `lsCustomer.ForEach(x => x.Email = ImportHelpers.GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace(x.Email))` (ForEach linq method, because this is already `List<T>`)

Comment: Are you sure the 10 seconds is just for the join and does not include the time to fetch the customers. You are also retrieving every field in the customer table, but only seem to be using code and email. Since the lsCustomer is a list, the join is working on in-memory objects, so whether or not Customer Email is indexed in the database is irrelevant. If the join really does take 10 seconds, then I suspect the problem must be in the ImportHelpers functions which must be taking the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @BurnsBA Are you sure? Whether pre-processing helps depends in the Linq implementation, but for Linq-To-Objects I think it will just call the method 202,000 times (rather than 2000 x 200000)

Comment: @BurnsBA Thanks. Your solution is the same as Svyatoslav Danyliv. In my case it solved the problem.

Comment: @sgmoore Thank. I debug and the problem is not with the ImportHelpers function. I actually don't understand the problem here. When I replace the Email field with the Code field (indexed in the DB), everything happens very quickly. I don't understand if the indexing in the DB is the cause of the difference.  
I'm still looking forward to a more holistic solution, such as switching to lookup search, instead of o(n*m) complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. Instead of GroupJoin, which is not needed here I have used `Join`. Also moved filters up in query.

```cs
var lsDuplicateEmail = 
    from imp in lsData
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.Email)
    join cust in lsCustomer
       on ImportHelpers.GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace(imp.Email) equals ImportHelpers.GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace(cust.Email)
    where !ImportHelpers.CompareString(imp.Code, cust.Code)
    select new
    {
        ImportItem = imp,
        CustomerItem = cust,
    };
```

Also show `GetPerfectStringWithoutSpace` implementation, maybe it is slow.

Another possible solution is to swap `lsData` and `lsCustomer` in query, maybe lookup search is not so fast.

Comment: In my case this solution solved the problem. When filtering the condition before joining, it reduces the size of the data a lot. Although the complexity is still 0(n*m).
I marked this as the answer that solved the problem.
If you have another solution to reduce complexity, please advise me.